# Session Variable keeps on resetting

Tags: php, session

I have database table which contains a number of questions each with corresponding answer options (multiple choice question).

The column in the table is like the following:

**questionID | questionText | answer | option1 | option 2 | option 3 | answerExplanation**

In my `session.php` file, I use PHP and mySQL to extract a single question (with answer options) from the database, which is held in the variable $question.

This `$question` is then used in my `index.php` file to show the question e.g.

```
Question: <?php echo $question['questionText'] ?>  
Option 1: <?php
    > echo $question['option1] ?> 
Option 2: <?php echo $question['option2']?>.
```

I would like to use SESSION to store an array of what questions the user has seen.

However, i'm having some difficulty with this. It seems like the session keeps on resetting with every new question.

Here is what my `session.php` is like:

```
<?php 
session_start();
echo session_id();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



// initialise session variable with array 
$_SESSION['questionhistory'] = [];

//Total Number of Questions in DB
$query_count = $conn->query("SELECT questionID FROM BBQuestions");
$totalquestions = $query_count->num_rows;


function findQuestion() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM BBQuestions ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $question = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $q_id = $question["questionID"]; //Get ID for question
    $q_id_integer = (int)$q_id; // Integer-ise the ID.

    // Checks to see if question is already seen (i.e. in SESSION['questionhistory'])
    if (in_array($q_id_integer, $_SESSION['questionhistory'])) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return $question;
    }
}


//checks to see if user has seen all questions 
function checkIfAllDone() {
    global $totalquestions;
    $x = count($_SESSION['questionhistory']); 
    if ($x == $totalquestions) {
        echo "ALL DONE";
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

$done = CheckIfAllDone();

//returns a question to be is echo-ed in index.php.
function pushQuestion() {
    global $done;
    $question = findQuestion();
    if ($done != 1) {
    while ($question == 0) {
        $question = findQuestion();
    }
    return $question;
}
}

$question = pushQuestion();  // question that is echo-ed in index.php

$question_json = json_encode($question);


$var = $question['questionID'];
array_push($_SESSION['questionhistory'], $var);

//Show whats in Array
foreach ($_SESSION['questionhistory'] as $item) {
echo $item . " - ";
}
```

How do i make sure the Session array updates with each new question seen?

Comment: How about you do _not_ initialize the session variable as an empty array every time …? `// initialise session variable with array`, `$_SESSION['questionhistory'] = [];` - dunno what exactly you expected to happen after these two lines.

Comment: @CBroe So then how I would I establish the array variable for $_SESSION to hold all the seen questions in?

Comment: Well you could check if that particular key is already set, and only initialize it with an empty array if not ... But that isn’t really necessary, PHP is capable of silently doing the initialization itself, as soon as you use `$_SESSION['questionhistory'][] = $var;` anywhere. (So you can just replace array_push with that.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you so much! That was exactly what I needed to know!